# The mean and Variance of $log(Combination Index)$

Tags: delta-method

In biological sciences, ($CI$) stands for the Combination Index which is a conventional method for dose-response assessment and drug interaction analysis. It can be defined as:

$$CI = 

\frac{\bar{D}_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}}{ln(\bar{SF}_{1}) - \hat\alpha_{1}} + \frac{\bar{SF}_{1}  - \hat{\alpha}_{2}}{{0.5} - \hat\alpha_{2}}$$

Notes:

1. $\bar{D}_{1}$ is independent of $(\hat\alpha_{1}, \hat\beta_{1})$.
2. $(\hat\alpha_{1}, \hat\beta_{1})$ are independent of $(\hat\alpha_{2})$.
3. $log(SF_{1}) = \alpha_{1} + \beta_{1} x + \epsilon$
4. $E(\bar{D}_{1}) = \mu_{D}$, and $Var(\bar{D}_{1}) = \sigma^{2}_{D}$

I'm trying to find $E({log(CI))}$ and $Var(log(CI))$. I know this can be done using delta method, but I'm not sure how... your help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: and $\epsilon$?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is the random term for the linear regression model which assumed to be normally distributed with mean zero and fixed variance.

Comment: OK, then personally I'd put away the pencil and paper and simulate a lot of values of $CI$ using the distributions of $\epsilon$ and $D_1$ with the parameter estimates you've got, then log 'em all and compute your quantities of interest.  Although I appreciate that's not your question, it seems like it would solve the practical problem of knowing how certain to be about $\log CI$.

Comment: I did find both the mean and variance of $log(CI)$ using bootstrapping, and now I'm trying to find an analytical form...